# how to repeat array and string

Tags: arrays, string, repeat

how to repeat array and string:

```
$name = array (ade, ian, yasin);
$title = 'IT';
```

How can repeat it so that the results are as follows ?

- ade IT
- ian IT
- yasin IT

thanks

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: *I want to repeat array and string*. Ok. Go ahead. You have our permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved

```
    <form method="post" action="#">
    isi :<input type="text" name="isi">
    title :<input type="text" name="title">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
<?php
  $rowCount = count($_POST['name']);
  $record=array();
  for ($i=0; $i<$rowCount;$i++)
  {
  $record[]=array(
    'nama' => $_POST['name'][$i],
    'isi' => $_POST['isi'],
    'title' =>$_POST['title']
    );
  }
  foreach ($record as $key => $a)
  {
  echo "".$a['nama'] ." ". $a['isi']." ".$a['title']."<br>";
  }

?>
```